# my numbers spreadsheet is all screwed up and I can't figure out why or how to fix it

Tags: numbers

It is as if my spreadsheet is overlapping itself...[image]

What is going on?!  how do I fix this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Quitt the app completely and try again

Comment: It seems that you have freezed column A. If so navigating from column A to B with keyboard using arrow key should reveal content of the whole column B.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find LibreOffice Calc much better than Numbers.  I usually prefer Apple to alternatives, but Numbers is a disappointment.

Comment: @WGroleau, yeah it blows my mind when trillion dollar companies have garbage software.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your Numbers file has two tables in the same location.

[Move the table](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/resize-move-or-lock-a-table-tancea35ff59/13.0/mac/1.0) in front to a new non-overlapping position: click on any cell to give the table focus, click and hold on the circle in the upper-left, drag the table to its new location and release.

[image: a screen recording of two tables occupying the same place at the same time, then one being moved away by drag-and-dropping its movement circle]